# Can't get amsul timepicker to update disable time after initialisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I use the wonderful date & time picker from amsul.ca/pickadate.js and can't get the timepicker to update the disabled time each time a new day is selected in the datepicker.

For example if I choose Tuesday, the time will be enabled from 12h to 15h.
If I come back to the datepicker and choose Wednesday, the enabled time should be updated to from 12h to 15h and from 19h to 22h.

But for now, the only way to set a new disabled time into the timepicker is to reload the page.

Many thanks for your help.

Cheers, 
Pierre

```
function setTimepicker(hours) {

var $input_time = $( '.timepicker' ).pickatime({
    formatLabel: 'H:i',
    formatSubmit: 'H:i',
    format: 'H:i',
    interval: opening.max_order_days,
    min: opening.min_time,
    max: opening.max_time,
    editable: false,
    disable: [
    { from: hours.f1 , to: hours.t1 }, 
    { from: hours.f2 , to: hours.t2 },
    { from: hours.f3 , to: hours.t3 }
    ]
}); 
}

var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({

onSet: function() {

    picker = this;

    pick_date_obj = picker.get('select', 'ddd');

    if(pick_date_obj) { 
        $('.timepicker').textinput({ disabled: false });
        $('#timepicker').val('Please select a time');
    } else {
        $('.timepicker').textinput({ disabled: true });
        $('#timepicker').val('Please select a date');
    }

    setTimepicker(getHours(pick_date_obj));

},

format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
firstDay: 1,
min: true,
max: opening.max_order_days,
editable: false, 
'disable': [ opening.disabled_day ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an open [issue](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/364). This [comment](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/364#issuecomment-116980300) helped me a lot.

Try this:

```
schedule_time.set('disable', true);
schedule_time.set('enable', false);

var enableDates = [
  { from: hours.f1 , to: hours.t1 }, 
  { from: hours.f2 , to: hours.t2 },
  { from: hours.f3 , to: hours.t3 }
];

schedule_time.set('disable', enableDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the picker added the disable time following the others, so not useful. I fix the problem using picker_time.set('disable', true); picker_time.set('enable', true) before setting the new disable time